# Add li to array and view with console.log

Tags: jquery, arrays, console

I have a simple ul list

```
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href=""><img src="images/01.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="images/02.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="images/03.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="images/04.jpg" /></a></li>
  </ul>
```

I would like to add the li's (with their contents) to an array then remove the li and then view the array with console.log
I'm using this.

```
  $(function(){

    var imgArr=[];

    $('#gallery li').each(function(){
      imgArr.push($(this));
      $(this).remove();
    })

    console.log(imgArr);

  })
```

I thought the console.log would show me a list of li's containing

```
    <a href=""><img src="images/01.jpg" /></a>
```

Instead I'm getting a list of Object[1]

Is this the correct way to add the li and contents?

How can I view the contents of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing jQuery objects into the array. Use `imgArr.push(this)` rather than `imgArr.push($(this))` to instead push the DOM Nodes.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5rAeH/

In the demo I removed your `.each` and instead used

```
var imgArr = $.makeArray($('#gallery li'));
console.log(imgArr);

$("#gallery li").remove();
console.log(imgArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your push to

```
imgArr.push($(this).html());
```

Now you will push the html into the array not the Jquery object.

Comment: How could I also include the surround li so each entry in the array is'<li><a href=""><img src="images/15.jpg" /></a></li>'

Comment: @user668499 use `this.outerHTML` rather than `$(this).html()` to get outer html.

Answer (score 1):

Your code need a modification, you have to add only "this" in your array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var imgArr=[];
  $('#gallery li').each(function(){
    imgArr.push(this);
    $(this).remove();
  })
  console.log(imgArr);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the contents of the array as **html** (as opposed to javascript object) do

```
$('#gallery li').each(function() {
    console.log(index + ': ' + $(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var imgArr=[];

    $('#gallery li').each(function(i,elm){
        imgArr[i] = elm.outerHTML;
        $(elm).remove();
    });
    console.log(imgArr);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5rMN/)